# Adding local user to local Administrators group in an Active Directory environment

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, active-directory

First, I know how to do what the title is asking.  My issue is figuring out why it fails in certain situations.  For some background, I need to create a local user account and add that user to the local admin group regardless if it is an AD environment or not.  The following code example works in most circumstances.

```
        Using pc = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName)
            Using gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "Administrators")
                If gp.Members.Contains(up) = False Then
                    gp.Members.Add(up)
                    gp.Save()
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
```

However, when logged in as an AD user but **disconnected** from the network, this throws "The network path was not found." exception.

```
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
 at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
 at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
 at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.ResolveCrossStoreRefToPrincipal(Object o)
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMMembersSet.MoveNextForeign()
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMMembersSet.MoveNext()
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalCollectionEnumerator.MoveNext()
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalCollection.ContainsEnumTest(Principal principal)
```

That makes sense except I would of thought it shouldn't be looking at the network for a local group.  I can successfully run this from the command line:

```
net localgroup administrators username /add
```

and it works fine.  So my question is, how can I programmatically add a local user to the local admin group regardless of network connectivity in both AD and non-AD environments.  If I have to just fallback to executing net.exe so be it, but it seems like there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: First, VS doesn't automatically run AS ADMIN.  The exe will run as admin but inside VS you have to create a shortcut to VS and then right click and select Run As Admin to debug code using VS and be an Admin.  Second for admin to work on remote machine you have to be admin on both local and remote machine. Third network paths for admin to work you need the dollar sign in the pathname.  May be create a separate app just for the adding the adding and set properties to Run As Admin.  Then call the app from c#.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with VS so your comment doesn't apply.

Comment: How do you develop vb.net without VS?

Comment: My question is about adding a local user to the local admin group in an disconnected AD environment.  It has nothing to do with VS and Run As Admin.

Comment: Does a normal user have privilege to perform operation?